# How to export two dimensional list to ascii file?

Tags: python, list, ascii

I am a beginner in Python and I guess my question is a bit stupid since what I intend to do seems easy. Anyway, I have a list which format is the following :

```
[(243.0, 233.63),
(279.0, 295.99),
(171.0, 233.63),
(279.0, 171.28),
       .
       .
       .
```

What I would like to do is just to export it into a file like this

```
243.0 233.63
279.0 295.99
171.0 233.63
279.0 171.28
       .
       .
       .
```

No comma, no brackets, etc... To do so I first export it as a csv file as follows

```
with open('nodes_position.txt', 'w') as f:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
    csv_writer.writerows(coordinates)
```

And then I have to convert this file to ascii format in order to use it in a C program, I think it is a bit tedious and would like to know what would be the best direct way to do so.

I am sorry if this has already been asked, I watched everywhere and did not find any satisfying answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [CSV writer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) takes a delimiter parameter that you can use so that you can use a space () as a delimiter instead of a comma (`,`)

```
with open('nodes_position.txt', 'w') as f:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=' ')
    csv_writer.writerows(coordinates)
```

The resultant file is ascii even though your original list contained floats. There is no need for further conversions.

Comment: Did it ! Thanks again !

Comment: All the best with your project